# I am not able to make div height 100% & scrollable in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af8rwac6/)

I am trying to make div of 100% height and also it should be scrollable when there is more content in that particular div.

I am using flex properties but my code not working properly - it doesn't scroll when the content is more than the div height.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial';
}
header,
footer {
  background: #333;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}
.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-box-flex: 2;
  /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  -moz-box-flex: 2;
  /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  /* Chrome */
  -ms-flex: 2;
  /* IE 10 */
  flex: 2;
  /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.content .inner_content {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.content .inner_content .left_content {
  display: table-cell;
  background: yellow;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.content .inner_content .right_content {
  display: table-cell;
  background: green;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.scrollable-content {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>this is header</header>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner_content">
      <div class="left_content">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/19704c162b4446c984a50bfdb49b45ac/a-colour-image-taken-on-a-cloudy-dawn-of-the-town-of-saint-malo-from-g1k27a.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="scrollable-content">
          <h1>I am trying to do:</h1>
          <h3>1) make these gray div height 100% till bottom</h3>
          <h3>2) When content is more then this gray div should be scrollable or else not</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="right_content">
        <img src="http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/19704c162b4446c984a50bfdb49b45ac/a-colour-image-taken-on-a-cloudy-dawn-of-the-town-of-saint-malo-from-g1k27a.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>this is footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this for you?

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header {
  background: grey
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  background: blue
}

.column {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.column:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}

.column:last-child {
  background: green;
}

.image-holder {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  background: orange;
  min-height:1%;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
}

.scrollable-content {
  flex: 1;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
  height: 10px;
}

.firefox-scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>header</header>
  <main>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/19704c162b4446c984a50bfdb49b45ac/a-colour-image-taken-on-a-cloudy-dawn-of-the-town-of-saint-malo-from-g1k27a.jpg" alt="" class="image">
      </div>
      <div class="scrollable-content">
        <div class="firefox-scroller">
          <h1>I am trying to do:</h1>
          <h3>1) make these gray div height 100% till bottom</h3>
          <h3>2) When content is more then this gray div should be scrollable or else not</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          </p>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/19704c162b4446c984a50bfdb49b45ac/a-colour-image-taken-on-a-cloudy-dawn-of-the-town-of-saint-malo-from-g1k27a.jpg" alt="" class="image">
      </div>

    </div>
  </main>
  <footer>this is footer</footer>
</div>
```

[Here is a fiddle for you to play with](https://jsfiddle.net/ptnpnefa/7)

Comment: What if there is more content is it going to be scrollable

Comment: thanks for the effort but when the content is more its not scrolling. the gray div should be scrool

Comment: I did but no its not scrolling, Can you give me fresh jsfiddle

Comment: sorry, just tested in firefox and it doesn't work - let me have a play

Comment: where is footer gone :(

Comment: footer added - no sweat

Comment: OOh i am sorry , that was missing from code only. good efforts

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the effect you want to get but try adding 'overflow' in that div CSS definition, for example:

```
.scrollable-content{
  background:#ddd;
  padding:10px;
  overflow: auto; max-height: 100%;
}
```

(I tried in the fiddle and it adds a scroll, is this the scroll you would like to get?)

Answer (score 0):

As far I am getting your thoughts, I think you are trying to get a fixed height for your div and if the contents are more, you want them to fit inside the div.

You can use a fixed height for your div and also can use the css **overflow** property to get the scroll-able content.

So I think your solution could be the following -

```
.scrollable-content{
    background:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    height: (your desired height goes here);
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: height should be adjustable till bottom, So i can't add height in pixels or percentage

Comment: In that case I think you can use the CSS calc() property.
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to set max height of your scrollable container.

```
 max-height: 100%;
```

Then you gotta say you want the vertical overflow be scrollable:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```